# Are finite abelian groups isomorphic to k-character groups for arbitrary alg.closed k?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, $k$ an algebraically closed field with group of units $k^{\times}$, and let $Ch_{k}(G)$ be the set of $k$-characters of $G$ whose elements are multiplicative homomorphisms of the form $\chi: G \to k^{\times}$ which forms a group under pointwise multiplication. On page 62 of Etingof et al. "Introduction to Representation theory" it is shown that $Ch_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $G$. Is this also true for an arbitrary algebraically closed field $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without constraint on the characteristic $p$ of the field $k$, a finite abelian group is not isomorphic to its $k$-character group. To be explicit, let $p > 0$ and $G \cong \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. Because the field $k$ does not have 'enough' $p$-th roots of unity (as $x^p - 1 = (x - 1)^p$ holds in $k$), we get
$$|\operatorname{Hom}(G, k^\times)| = |\{\, x \in k : x^p = 1 \,\}| = 1.$$
So it cannot be isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Right. It is in fact isomorphic to the "outside $p$" part of $G$.

Comment: @WhatsUp By “outside $p$ part” do you mean modding out p power torsion in G?

Comment: Since $G$ is abelian, it is (by Chinese remainder theorem) isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. The "outside $p$ part" simply means removing the $p$-Sylow in the direct product.

Comment: Actually this is nice so as a generalization of this example if I have a finite abelian group $G$ and another finit. Ab. $H$ Which differs  from $G$ by removing a Sylow p-subgroup in the decomposition I can always choose an alg, closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$ to recover $H$ as the $k$ character group of $G$ right? Is that true in general or did I jump too far?

Comment: The Hall $p'$-subgroup of $G$ is a formal terminology for what WhatsUp calls "outside $p$" part of $G$, informally. I think $\operatorname{Hom}(G_1, k^\times) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G_2, k^\times)$ iff $H_1 \cong H_2$ is true for finite abelian groups $G_i$ with Hall $p'$-subgroups $H_i$ and a field $k$ of characteristic $p > 0$ containing a primitive $e$-th root of unity where $e$ denotes the exponent of $H_i$. I also believe that the proof is the same as $\mathbf C$ case; but you should try to prove it as I have not seen the statement with this generality.