# What is the example of non canonical isom?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, ring-isomorphism

In mathematics, isomorphism $f$ between two objects are sometimes called canonical
when $f$ is unique as a map, in other words, everyone choose the same map, no different map gives the isomorphism.

Could you give me an example of non canonical map, and explain why that is not canonical ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your first paragraph is confused: there is a big difference between "everyone choosing the same map", and "no different map gives the isomorphism". The Wiki article explains quite well how the word canonical is used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_map

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586013/are-finite-abelian-groups-isomorphic-to-k-character-groups-for-arbitrary-alg-clo): The character group $Ch_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do people mean with "canonical"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152059/what-do-people-mean-with-canonical)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094826/deeper-meaning-of-canonical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$I am not so sure about your definition of *canonical*. As I understand it, it is an isomorphism that does not depend on a particular choice.

The standard example is given by a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and its dual $V^{\star}$. An isomorphism between the two depends on the choice of a base on $V$. (Addendum. The point should be that an element $0 \ne f \in V^{\star}$ is determined by its kernel $K$, which is a hyperplane of $V$, and then a vector $v \notin K$ such that $f(v) = 1$. But even when $K \ne \{ 0 \}$ is given, there are many such vectors, as $f(v) = 1$ implies $f(v + k) = 1$ for $k \in K$, so there is no way to associate in a base-independent way an element of $V^{\star}$ to a vector of $V$.)

The situation is different with $V$ and its bidual $V^{\star\star}$, as the map
$$
v \mapsto (f \mapsto f(v))
$$
is an isomorphism that does not depend on any particular choice. But there are of course many other isomorphisms, just compose this one with an element of $\GL(V)$.

Comment: Is 'Isom that does not depend on a particular choice' and 'canonical isom' dirrefent concept ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the words are used slightly differently in different areas. @Andreas Caranti has given you the standard example of how the words are used in linear algebra, essentially to mean "defined without reference to any particular basis".

In group theory I think the words are used in a weaker sense.

As you have tagged this "groups" here is a non-canonical isomorphism between $A_4/V$ and $A_3$. (Here $A_3$, $A_4$ are the alternating groups of orders $3$ and $12$ and $V$ is the normal subgroups of order $4$ in $A_4$).

Define $f:A_3\to A_4/V$ by $f(e)=V$, $f((123))=(132)V$, $f((132))=(123)V$. You can check that this is an isomorphism. However the canonical isomorphism - the one "we would all choose" - does not swap the $3$-cycles in this way.

Comment: I am a group theorist by trade. Given a group $G$, if one had to define a *canonical* isomorphism $G \to G$, this would no doubt be the identity map. But this of course does not mean that the other automorphisms of a group are not important.